# Using J's interface to C shared libraries on linux (dll's)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, j

I would like to use some functions form a shared library on Linux. 
I could not find any recent documentation. After reading [this](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/call_procedure.htm) I tried the following

```
  load 'dll'
  '/lib64/libc.so putchar i i' cd <65
|domain error: cd
|   '/lib64/libc.so putchar i i'    cd<65
  '/lib64/libc.so atoi i *c' cd <'22'
|domain error: cd
|   '/lib64/libc.so atoi i *c'    cd<'22'
```

Where is the mistake ?

Comment: The last one - j64-804

Comment: run your commands again, then run `cder''` and `cderx''` and read [this](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/cd_domain_error.htm). also update your question with the output of above commands

Comment: and btw, i wonder about your path. according to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/libc.7.html) you should refer to the C library as `libc.so.6`, don't ask why :)

Comment: another little comment: `putchar c i`, otherwise you wont see anything usefull, just passing the integer, and returning the same (in numeric format). i know that the declaration is `int putchar(int)`, but when you get things working you'll see what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It seems J doesn't follow symbolic links, the following works correctly:</s>

```
'/lib64/libc-2.20.so putchar c i' cd <65
A┌─┬──┐
│A│65│
└─┴──┘
```

Where `/lib64/libc-2.20.so` is the library to which the `libc.so.6` link points.

PS. Thanks @Danylo Dubinin for the `cder''` and `cderx''` tips ! :)

**UPDATE:** It is embarrassing: `/lib64/libc.so` is not a shared library, its a "GNU ld script" but `/lib64/libc.so.6` is a link to a shared library that J correctly follows, so I was just specifying the wrong path  ... eh

Comment: I'm not sure that explains it. That command works fine for me if I point it at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` which is a symbolic link to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so`. And if I create a 2nd symbolic link to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` in my home directory and call that instead, the command continues to work fine.

Comment: I'm glad my comments helped you to solve the problem. [unix.stackexchage](http://unix.stackexchange.com) is good place to search unix-related issues. I've found a lot of usefull information related to your problem in [this topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120380/). As a rule of thumb: `man` pages to help. Also try `ldd /bin/ls` or any other standard unix utility - you'll always find how the C library is called :)